# How to perform data validation on data from source files into CRM Dynamics 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Is it possible to perform data validation on fields from external source files(.csv,xml,txt) using the out of the box CRM Import Wizard? or do I need to perform validation using the CRM Web service SDK in say a plugin or so, please advice on best approach for this m i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to do data validations is in plugins, i.e. in the pre-validation and pre-operation stages of the create and update messages.